# nav menu with separate links for each page

Tags: html

I have created a html/css nav menu bar with 5 links and it works. When I click on each of the link, the corresponding page is displayed in the current page/window, replacing the page which had navigation menu displayed. I need the navigation menu to stay on the top and the content from the page should be displayed in the remaining portion of the menupage . How can I accomplish this ?

I found an option to use IFrame and target each href to the iframe.
Not sure if that is the correct approach.

The html code for the menu page is as follows

```
<body>
<header>
    <ul class = "nav">
        <li class = "navlink"> <a href="homepage.html"> Home </a> <li>
        <li class = "navlink"> <a href="products.html"> Products </a> <li>
        <li class = "navlink"> <a href="orderstatus.html"> Order status </a> <li>
        <li class = "navlink"> <a href="support.html"> Customer Support </a> <li>
    </ul>
</header>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the go to a new browser tap by adding `target="_blank"`to your HTML like this :

```html
<body>
<header>
    <ul class = "nav">
        <li class = "navlink"> <a href="homepage.html" target="_blank"> Home </a> <li>
        <li class = "navlink"> <a href="products.html" target="_blank"> Products </a> <li>
        <li class = "navlink"> <a href="orderstatus.html" target="_blank"> Order status </a> <li>
        <li class = "navlink"> <a href="support.html" target="_blank"> Customer Support </a> <li>
    </ul>
</header>

</body>
```

if you want them to remain on the same page I recommend you to try a 1 page approach were you use `#` to target a specific id, for example :

```html
<body>
<header>
    <ul class = "nav" style = "display:flex;list-style:none;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;">
        <li class = "navlink"> <a href="#homepage"> Home </a> <li>
        <li class = "navlink"> <a href="#products"> Products </a> <li>
        <li class = "navlink"> <a href="#orderstatus"> Order status </a> <li>
        <li class = "navlink"> <a href="#support"> Customer Support </a> <li>
    </ul>
</header>

<section id="homepage">
<h1>homepage</h1>
<h1>homepage</h1>
<h1>homepage</h1>
<h1>homepage</h1>
<h1>homepage</h1>
<h1>homepage</h1>
<h1>homepage</h1>
<h1>homepage</h1>
<h1>homepage</h1>
<h1>homepage</h1>
<h1>homepage</h1>
<h1>homepage</h1>
</section>


<section id="products">
<h1>products</h1>
<h1>products</h1>
<h1>products</h1>
<h1>products</h1>
<h1>products</h1>
<h1>products</h1>
<h1>products</h1>
<h1>products</h1>
<h1>products</h1>
<h1>products</h1>
<h1>products</h1>
<h1>products</h1>
<h1>products</h1>
<h1>products</h1>
</section>


<section id="orderstatus">
<h1>orderstatus</h1>
<h1>orderstatus</h1>
<h1>orderstatus</h1>
<h1>orderstatus</h1>
<h1>orderstatus</h1>
<h1>orderstatus</h1>
<h1>orderstatus</h1>
<h1>orderstatus</h1>
<h1>orderstatus</h1>
<h1>orderstatus</h1>
<h1>orderstatus</h1>
<h1>orderstatus</h1>
<h1>orderstatus</h1>
<h1>orderstatus</h1>
<h1>orderstatus</h1>
<h1>orderstatus</h1>
<h1>orderstatus</h1>
<h1>orderstatus</h1>
</section>


<section id="support">
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
<h1>support</h1>
</section>

</body>
```

Comment: I need the individual html page to stay on the same menu page under the displayed nav menu. The "#" solution doesn't work because, the individual pages are complex and need to separate html files

Answer (score 0):

**ReactJS:**
You can create component for navbar and export it.

**PHP:**
You can create file for navbar and include this file in a page you want.

In pure HTML you can do this by rewrite your nav code

Comment: Sorry, but did not understand the third part "In pure HTML you can do this by rewrite your nav code"

Comment: Sorry, it's HTML only